# How can I take multiple years selected from a slicer to assign each into var

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to let my user choose on a slicer up to 5 years and catch each year on a var in a measure to use as a filter later in calculations

Currently I am using year1=min([year]),year2=average([year]),year3=max([year]) to catch 3 years but if want more I can't using these methods.

Comment: Have you looked at combining `VALUES` with `IN`? For example, `=VAR ChosenYears=VALUES([MyYearSlicer]) RETURN CALCULATE([MyMeasure], [MyYearColumn] IN Chosen Years)`?

Comment: this one can return all years together but I want to catch the first one selected and assign it to a variable then the second one assigned to a second variable as they will all be used in calculations later on I don't think this method helps in this case

Comment: So use something like `Year1:=TOPN(1,TOPN(1,VALUES(Years[Year]),Years[Year],ASC))`, `Year2:=TOPN(1,TOPN(2,VALUES(Years[Year]),Years[Year],ASC))`, etc.

Comment: Yes it worked many thanks perfectly resolved

Comment: I am sorry just tested it again and found out that for some reason it doesn't work properly and gives wrong years if the selected number of years isn't larger than the max year you have and the solution that worked perfectly for me was in this format : 
var Year1=MAXx(TOPN(1,VALUES(ref_fac_table[YEAR]),ref_fac_table[YEAR],ASC),ref_fac_table[YEAR])
var Year2=MAXx(TOPN(2,VALUES(ref_fac_table[YEAR]),ref_fac_table[YEAR],ASC),ref_fac_table[YEAR]) ......

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Year1 :=
TOPN( 1, TOPN( 1, VALUES( Years[Year] ), Years[Year], ASC ) )

Year2 :=
TOPN( 1, TOPN( 2, VALUES( Years[Year] ), Years[Year], ASC ) )
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can let the user select multiple years and assign one of them for each variable as values will take the year column and make it a vector then the TOPN will order it ascending therefore, we will always have the selected year as the last option then MAXx will take the last one of the list which will be accordingly to the year assigned

```
var Year1=MAXx( TOPN( 1, VALUES( ref_fac_table[YEAR]), ref_fac_table[YEAR],ASC) , ref_fac_table[YEAR]) 

var Year2= MAXx (TOPN (2,VALUES (ref_fac_table[YEAR]) ,ref_fac_table[YEAR],ASC), ref_fac_table[YEAR])....
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**